# How to calculate Total with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the  table with item, quantity and price. I am able to update price for each row on quantity change.

But now I want to add all prices and show the total . I did write a total function , but is not helping.

**View**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <th>Items</th>
        <th>Description</th> 
        <th>Quantity</th>

        <th>Price</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="item in items">

    <td><img ng-src={{item.ImageUrl}} title="{{item.Name}}" 
             class="img-thumbnail" height="100" width="100" ><br/>
        {{item.Name}}
    </td>
    <td>{{item.Description}}</td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" max="{{item.Quantity}}" ng-model="currentQuantity"/></td>
    <td ng-model="currentPrice">{{item.Price*currentQuantity}}</td>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td>Total</td>       
            <td>{{Total()}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**Model & Controller:**

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("FoodItems", []);

  var serviceUrl = "http://localhost/MkitechenService/Api/FoodItems";

  var MainController = function($scope, $http) {


  $scope.currentQuantity=1;
   $scope.currentPrice=0;

  $scope.Total = function()
  {
      currentPrice +=currentPrice;
      return 100;
  };

var onItemsLoaded = function(response) {
  console.log(response.data);
  $scope.items = response.data;

};

var onError = function(reason) {
  console.log(reason.message);

};

$http.get(serviceUrl).then(onItemsLoaded, onError);


  };


  app.controller("MainController", MainController);

}());
```

Comment: this `<td ng-model` not make sense

Comment: Also the input's `ng-model` should be `item.currentQuantity`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-repeat` create own scope, and

```
ng-model="currentQuantity"
```

add property `currentQuantity` to this scope, so you can't get it outside this scope.

But you can save it in `item`, just use

```
ng-model="item.currentQuantity"
```

After that, in `Total` function you should just go over items collection, and sum `item.currentQuantity`, like this

```
$scope.Total = function()
{
    return $scope.items.reduce(function(total,item){
        return total + (item.currentQuantity*item.Price || 0);//for case when this filed not filled
    },0);
};
```

Comment: This works , updating the total quantity ,but there is a problem. When I change the quantity , it's just updating the total price, not the price column of that row.Earlier it was updating row price , not the total . I want both

Comment: @Simsons, do you change `item.Price*currentQuantity` to `item.Price*item.currentQuantity`?

Comment: Thanks,why the method is named as .reduce !!

Comment: @Simsons, because it [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) collection :-)